# C++ large string initialization and use

Tags: c++, c, arrays, string, std

Hi I have an array of around 500 strings. Multiple functions in my class use this variable. I obviously do not want to initialize that array multiple times throughout my program. What would be the most efficient method to initialize it once and be able to use it throughout the class?

Here is an example of what I mean:

SomeClass.h:

```
class SomeClass {
   public:
        static const std::string large_list[];
   private:
        void someFunc();
        void someFunc2();
        void someFunc3();
}
```

SomeClass.cpp:

```
void SomeClass::someFunc1(){
        static std::string large_list[] = {"something", "somethingelse", "somethingelse1"...};
        //do something with the large_list
   }

    void SomeClass::someFunc2(){
        static std::string large_list[] = {"something", "somethingelse", "somethingelse1"...};
        //do something with the large_list
   }

    void SomeClass::someFunc3(){
        static std::string large_list[] = {"something", "somethingelse", "somethingelse1"...};
        //do something with the large_list
   }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Easier to use a `std::vector` or something, or make it `constexpr`.

Comment: If the string doesnt change during the program make it const otherwise the way used is fine.

Comment: Could you explain memory wise how this method is ok to use? It doesn't seem efficient to continuously create the same large array multiple times in different functions.

Comment: What compiler are you using (are you able to use C++11)?

Comment: If the string is not being modified by your functions, you can initialize once in constructor. Note that in the way you are doing now, you are creating local variables inside each functions (ie.,not using the class variable)

Comment: static members always get initialized only once (esp true in C++11). The way it is used should be fine.

Comment: Each function has its own copy of large_array[] and the class static is never defined.  Or is this something C++11 changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following in-class initialization (note I didn't use `std::string` since it's constructor is not `constexpr`):

```
class SomeClass {
   public:
        static constexpr const char* large_list[] = {"something", "somethingelse", "somethingelse1"};
};
```

Comment: Compiled with C++11 and received the error: /tmp/ccUWQUct.o: In function `SomeClass::someFunc1()':
SomeClass.cpp:(.text+0x19d9): undefined reference to `SomeClass::large_list'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: You have to define it in your cpp file, add `constexpr const char* SomeClass::large_list[];`

Comment: Completely forgot to do that. Thanks!